# extracting substring by lines

Tags: java

I am fairly new to programming so please bear with me. Say I have a large string such as this.

> String story = "This is the first line.\n" 
>                + "This is the second line.\n" 
>                + "This is the third line\n" 
>                + "This is the fourth line.\n" 
>                + "This is the fifth line.";

How would I go about extracting the first, fourth, and so on lines?

Comment: You should consider using System.getProperty("line.separator") as line break, not \n, because this would be plattform specific.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to avoid creating arrays, you can use [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(story);
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] lines = story.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
String firstLine = lines[0];
// and so on
```

You can split on `\n`, but thus you are fixed to the line separator of *nix systems. If it happens that you have to parse on windows, splitting on `\n` won't work (unless of course your string is hard-coded, which defeats the whole purpose of splitting - you know which are the lines beforehand)

Answer (score 4):

You can split your string into lines using the [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method and then index to get the line you want:

```
String story =
    "This is the first line.\n" +
    "This is the second line.\n" +
    "This is the third line\n" +
    "This is the fourth line.\n" +
    "This is the fifth line."; 

String[] lines = story.split("\n");
String secondLine = lines[1];
System.out.println(secondLine);
```

Result:

```
This is the second line.
```

Notes:

- In Java indexing arrays starts at zero, not one. So the first line is `lines[0]`.
- The split method takes a regular expressions as its argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] lines = story.split('\n');

String line_1 = lines[0];
String line_4 = lines[3];
```

or something along those lines

Answer (score 1):

If the string is going to be very long, you can use a combination of a BufferedReader and a StringReader to do it one line at a time:

```
String story = ...;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(story));

while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
   if (str.length() > 0) System.out.println(str);
}
```

Otherwise, split the string into an Array, if it's small enough using `Split`:

```
String[] lines = story.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You would split the string into an array and then select the array elements you want

```
String[] arr = story.split("\n")
arr[0] // first line
arr[3] // fourth line
```

Comment: it doesn't return an `ArrayList`